# Adding popover to bsCollapsePanel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs, bslib

I have a Shiny application which has collapse panels. I want to be able to add a popover to the collapse panel the same way I have added to the `textInput(id = 'myText')`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyBS::bsCollapse(
    id = "all_panels", 
    open = c("My Panel"),
    shinyBS::bsCollapsePanel(
      title = "My Panel",
      textInput(inputId = "myText", label = "Some Label") %>% popify(title = "A Title", trigger = "hover", placement = "top", content = "Popover Content")
    ) %>% popify(title = "A Title", trigger = "hover", placement = "bottom", content = "Popover Content")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in if (getAttribs(panels[[i]])$value %in% open) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

If I remove the `bsCollapse(...)` and have the `bsCollapsePanel(...)` on it's own I do not get the error and the popup shows as intended. But I then loose the capability of of opening and closing collapse panels by referring to their title.

I have tried adding an `id = 'myPanel'` parameter to `bsCollapsePanel()` and then on the `server()` side added:

```
addPopover(
    session = session,
    id = "myPanel",
    title = "SomeTitle",
    content = "SomeContent",
    trigger = "click"
  )
```

but that didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem with your attempt `bsCollapsePanel() %>% popify()` arises if you use `placement = "top"` similar to the `textInput` because the `bsCollapsePanel()` is on the top of your page and then the popover is outside of the visible area. The popover gets visible e.g. if you use `bsCollapsePanel() %>% popify()` with `placement = "bottom"`. Otherwise you have to move the panel or be more specific where you want to place the popover.

Comment: @Jan - You are write, making `placement = 'bottom'` did show the popup. I also added some `br()` before the collapse panel to create space and it worked.

In the repex added (which I have now updated) I hadn't added the collapse panel to a `bsCollapse()` group - doing which the the following error is thrown `Error in if (getAttribs(panels[[i]])$value %in% open) { : argument is of length zero` . I have updated the question to include this too.